# Is ‘kol tuv’ a religious phrase?

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, hebrew, social-convention

I often hear religious people saying the phrase ‘Kol tuv’ - May everything be good by you.

Is there any history behind the wide usage in religious communities, other than it being said in Hebrew?

Comment: First pasuk of shelishi of Chayei Sarah

Comment: @Heshy That only proves it's Hebrew, no?

Comment: Yeah it wasn't intended to be a full answer.  But "tuv" as opposed to "tov" is weird.  There it's samuch to אדניו, in the popular saying it's not explicitly samuch to anything.  I assume that pasuk is the source.

Comment: @Heshy Ah, I concur.

Comment: I would assume that it is from bentching as in "U'mi'kol Tuv al yi'chasrainu". If you are looking for a Tuv vs Tov source.

Comment: I suspect it's an abbreviated form of שלוכט"ס which has a little longer history as a greeting

Comment: can you clarify your question? Are you asking about "tov' vs "tuv"? About the idea of just saying those two words which are only a sentence fragment? Where those words came from in the first place? Why people say that as opposed to different possible blessings? What specifically are you asking about?

Comment: @Binyomin He's asking if it's a religious phrase. If the answers to any of your questions help answer that, one can provide that info in an answer.

Comment: Oh there's also ובתים מלאים כל טוב which is also tuv.  I think I was wrong about the grammer

Comment: @user22181 In most old manuscripts and printings, the wording in bentching is "veshalom vekhol tov umikol tov" eg. https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45010&st=&pgnum=24 https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20154&st=&pgnum=13

Comment: It seems to be quite general. We have this saying in my native language too, which might have come from the _Alles Gute zu_ German phrase.